# Quitar escala negativa ng2-charts

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy trabajando con `ng2-charts` y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de quitar la escala negativa`de la`grafica`cuando esta este en`0`, solamente ocupo que se muestren`la escala positiva`, estoy utilizando`Line Chart`.

[image: quiero eliminar la escala negativa de esta grafica cuando este en 0]

este es el codigo de la grafica

```
public lineChartData:Array<any> = [
    { data: [], label: 'Litros'}
];


public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = [];
public lineChartOptions:any = {
    responsive: true
};

public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
    { // grey
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(72, 208, 255, 0.5)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(72, 208, 255, 1)',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
        pointBorderColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }
];

public lineChartLegend:boolean = true;
public lineChartType:string = 'line';
```

Comment: Tienes que editar el array para que los valores menores a cero sean cero. O algun valor minimo que quieras tener.

Comment: Muestra el fragmento de tu codigo respectivo para tener unar mejor idea

Comment: El problema es que yo no utilizo valores negativos nunca, solo quiero que la escala negativa de la grafica de la imagen no se muestre, solo quiero la positiva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NG2-Charts usa por debajo la libreria chart.js y lo que pides se soluciona a partir de la options del chart.

En primer lugar, en tu componente has de declarar un objeto donde definas las opciones que quieras aplicar a tu gráfica. En este caso, la parte que te interesa son los scales y el eje Y:

```
this.chartOptions = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Y luego, pasarle ese chartOptions al objecto en tu template:

```
<canvas [options]="chartOptions"...>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono